# Is it possible to register Python VM inputs and replay them?

Tags: python

*Note: I don't know how the Python virtual machine works*

If Python has a vm, it wouldn't be possible to register every generic input (like standard input, socket reading, file reading) into a log file in order to replay it to get a very similar results?

I was thinking about this possibility because I imagine that a user, who has found a bug in my program, could send to me this log file, which contains everything he has done.

It could be useful or is my thought faulty? If not, how it could be achieved? Does exist something similar?

Comment: The term "virtual machine" has several meanings. You may be confusing some of those.

Comment: @delnan I was thinking about it because I suppose that a low-level solution, if possible and if it worth it, could works better (less overhead, no compatibility problems).

Comment: Well, you can replace `sys.stdout`/`sys.stdin`/`sys.stderr` and also the `open` function and whatever you like with some custom object that records this in a log file.
Anyway I don't know how much this would help. There is already a `logging` module that allows you to organize logging messages for your application. Usually that's enough.